# Android activity in java with XML crashes

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I am kinda a newb to Android development.  I am trying to display a simple activity written entirely in Java without XML, but it crashes.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstancestate)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedinstancestate);
        RelativeLayout thislayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams TextViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        TextViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        TextView outputtext = new TextView(this);
        outputtext.setText("Poop!");
        thislayout.addView(outputtext, TextViewParams);
        setContentView(thislayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your error log?

Comment: I just get the error "Unfortunately, TestJavaLayout has stopped."  I can't test this with an emulator because I have an AMD processor which doesn't support the emulation in Android Studio

Comment: look for logcat in your studio.. it will show you at where you are getting it wrong.

Comment: If it makes a difference, this activity is displayed after a button in the main activity is clicked.  If it is relevant, the code in the main activity that displays this activity is as follows:    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

Comment: When are you getting crash..After clicking the button or before clicking the button..??

Comment: Have you declared your TestActivity in Manifest file too.

Comment: I have checked your code in my side except this no problem in your code @user6191667

Answer (score 1):

Okey you are initializing `LayoutParams` but not setting it to `TextView`. And also you have to define `LayoutParams` for Parent Layout i.e `RelativeLayout` as well.

I tested your code and made some changes. **try do do this**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstancestate) {
    super.onCreate(savedinstancestate);

    // setting RelativeLayout Params
    RelativeLayout thislayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    thislayout.setLayoutParams(params);

    // setting TextView Params
    TextView outputtext = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams TextViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    TextViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    outputtext.setLayoutParams(TextViewParams);
    outputtext.setText("Poop!");

    thislayout.addView(outputtext);
    setContentView(thislayout);
}
```

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {



     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
            TextView programmedTextView=new TextView(this);
            programmedTextView.setText("Setting my textView programmatically");
            programmedTextView.setTextSize(20);
            relativeLayout.addView(programmedTextView);
            this.setContentView(relativeLayout,new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

be correct in writing topic, obviously you mean "Android activity in java with **NO** XML crashes".

Second, seems you forgot to describe your activity in manifest file, like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="io.github.d2edev.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".main.TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

At least, this worked for me. Have a nice day!